# JS/jQuery : Amend contents of div contenteditable and refocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, contenteditable, onkeyup

**My Aim:**

To be able to add/amend the content inside my content editable user input div on 'keyup' and be able to refocus it so that the user is not interupted.

**My Problem:**

Content Editable div fails to properly refocus.

**My Example:**

http://jsbin.com/owoto4/4/

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - this works as I expect it to: On key up, you replace the HTML of the div with `content amended` so every keystroke the user makes results in the character being typed being overwritten with `content amended`.

Comment: I am using chrome and the blinking caret disappears after the html amendment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution that is more effective than the .focus() method:

```
  $.fn.placeCaretAtEnd = function(){
    var el = $(this)[0];
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
      && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      range.collapse(false);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
      var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
      textRange.moveToElementText(el);
      textRange.collapse(false);
      textRange.select();
    }
  }
```

**USAGE:**

```
$('#myContenteditable').placeCaretAtEnd();
```